# How to sum only part of items in SQL (Pivot Table)

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot-table

I have a table of orders containing information about the customer (*Customer* field), unloading point (*Warehouse*), item code (*Item*), order date (*OrderDate*) and requested delivery date (*DeliveryDate*).

| Customer | Warehouse | Item | Quantity | OrderDate | DeliveryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 | 50 | 1.1.2022 | 2.2.2022 |
| A | A1 | 1 | 60 | 1.1.2022 | 2.2.2022 |
| A | A1 | 1 | 70 | 1.1.2022 | 3.3.2022 |
| A | A1 | 2 | 20 | 1.1.2022 | 3.3.2022 |
| A | A2 | 2 | 30 | 1.1.2022 | 3.3.2022 |
| A | A2 | 2 | 10 | 1.1.2022 | 4.4.2022 |
| A | A2 | 2 | 10 | 1.1.2022 | 5.5.2022 |
| A | A1 | 1 | 20 | 2.2.2022 | 4.4.2022 |
| A | A1 | 1 | 30 | 2.2.2022 | 5.5.2022 |
| A | A1 | 2 | 50 | 2.2.2022 | 4.4.2022 |
| A | A2 | 1 | 10 | 2.2.2022 | 7.7.2022 |
| A | A2 | 1 | 20 | 2.2.2022 | 8.8.2022 |
| A | A2 | 3 | 30 | 2.2.2022 | 9.9.2022 |
| B | B2 | 3 | 10 | 1.1.2022 | 5.5.2022 |
| B | B1 | 3 | 10 | 1.1.2022 | 5.5.2022 |

The customer sends orders of items for multiple delivery days. There can be multiple delivery dates for one month.

I would like to use a SQL query to do a sum by month of just the first order of items to a supplier for a specific warehouse and all delivery dates.

| Key | II | III | IV | V | VII | VIII | IX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA11 | 110 | 70 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| AA12 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| AA21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 20 | 0 |
| AA22 | 0 | 30 | 10 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| AA23 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 30 |
| BB13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| BB23 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am using **MS Access**, into which I have imported the data from the purchase orders. I have created this query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Sheet1.Quantity) AS SumOfMnožství
SELECT [Customer]+"+"+[Warehouse]+"+"+[Item] AS Code, First(Sheet1.OrderDate) AS FirstOfOdvolavka
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY [Customer]+"+"+[Warehouse]+"+"+[Item]
PIVOT Month([DeliveryDate]);
```

The result of the query will show in the rows of the first order for the combination customer + warehouse + item. In the columns are the months. The problem is the total, which is not just for the first order displayed, but for all orders.

**How to modify the query to only sum up the values for the first (the oldest) orders?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A couple of things to watch for - The use of First is very unlikely to give you what you want, I would use Min(OrderDate). Secondly, you will need to only return that value. There is nothing in your query grouping to achieve that. To simplify things create an initial query that only brings in the first order per customer per month first then pivot that queries results,

Comment: Retrieving X number of records per group is a common topic. More than one method to accomplish. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74707362/sql-query-for-ms-access-to-show-top-5-values-for-aggregated-values-by-group

Comment: Note that **&** character is preferred operator for concatenation.

Comment: If this data is multi-year, probably need to extract year from DeliveryDate and apply filter criteria.

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data as text table, not image.

Comment: @Minty I tried to simplify the problem to two queries, but I'm not good enough at SQL to get the result.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the tips. I looked at the links, I roughly understand what the point is, but I don't know SQL enough to write a proper query.

Comment: With the sample data provided and defined rules for selection, all records will be included in the output calculation. Your attempted CROSSTAB produces the same result as my more complicated answer using your rules for selecting records. Your sample output table is missing data for delivery months 4 and 5. Perhaps you need to further clarify what a 'first order' is and what delivery dates are associated. Why is there no OrderNumber in your data?

Answer (score 2):

I realized TOP N won't work for one reason is need to pull all delivery dates for each first order retrieved. Also, CROSSTAB did not like using TOP N dataset. So, consider:

Query1

```
SELECT Sheet1.*
FROM Sheet1 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT Customer, Warehouse, Item, Format(OrderDate, "yyyymm") AS YrMo, Min(OrderDate) AS MinOD 
     FROM Sheet1 GROUP BY Customer, Warehouse, Item, Format(OrderDate, "yyyymm"))  AS Q 
ON (Sheet1.OrderDate= Q.MinOD) AND (Sheet1.Item = Q.Item) AND (Sheet1.Warehouse = Q.Warehouse) AND (Sheet1.Customer = Q.Customer);
```

Query2

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Query1.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
SELECT Query1.Customer, Query1.Warehouse, Query1.Item, Year([DeliveryDate]) AS Yr
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Customer, Query1.Warehouse, Query1.Item, Year([DeliveryDate])
PIVOT Month([DeliveryDate]);
```